# CentOS yum missing depency kernel >= but kernel is already >=

Tags: linux, centos, nginx

I am trying to install Nginx on a CentoOS server and having a hard time.

I am new to CentOS for the most part but I am familiar with Debian (but this server has to be CentOS)

After adding the EPEL repo I ran:

```
yum install nginx
```

It did its thing up until this point:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
nginx-0.8.55-1.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
--> Missing Dependency: kernel >= 2.6.18-181 is needed by package nginx-0.8.55-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: kernel >= 2.6.18-181 is needed by package nginx-0.8.55-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Here is the output of uname -a:

```
Linux FQDN 2.6.38.2-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #2 SMP Thu Aug 25 16:40:22 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thank you.

Luma

Comment: What's the output of `rpm -qi kernel`?

Comment: # rpm -qi kernel
package kernel is not installed  - The company that hosts this server uses a lot of custom stuff and I am thinking they use a custom Kernel and have tweaked yum/rpm but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no package named "kernel" in your rpmdb that matches that requirement. And for some reason or another (probably because of some limitation regarding your server) the kernel package has been excluded in the Yum configuration, preventing it from being installed. You cannot resolve this via Yum until you figure out why the kernel package has been excluded.

Of course, you could always just install nginx from source instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can install kernel from CentOS repository (this one looks line the one installed by OVH or BurstNet), by first purging this kernel from rpmdb

Something like:
rpm -e kernel --justdb

Would remove kernel info from RPM database, but not kernel files.
After that you can try installing nginx
Edit grub file afterwards, to make sure you still loading same kernel.

Probably a bit better approach would be:

yum install yum-utils
yumdownloader nginx
rpm -ivh nginx*rpm --nodeps

That will download the RPM locally, and will install it skipping dependencies.